# Как записать значения функции в файл Python?

Tags: python

Вот мой код :

```
# _*_ coding: utf-8 _*_
import os
import time
from threading import Thread, current_thread
import requests
from Queue import Queue
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

domain_file = "domains.txt"
domain_temp = "temp"
theard_count = 15

def check_url(host):
    try:
        url = requests.get('https://www.alexa.com/minisiteinfo/' + host + '')
        code = url.status_code
        url.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser').table.a.get_text()
        i = soup.replace(',', '')
        rank = int(i.strip(" "))
        print(rank)
        if rank > 0:
            return True, rank
    except:
       return False
    return False

def run(queue, result_queue):
    # Цикл продолжается пока очередь задач не станет пустой
    while not queue.empty():
        # получаем первую задачу из очереди
        host = queue.get_nowait()
        # проверяем URL
        status = check_url(host)
        # сохраняем результат для дальнейшей обработки
        result_queue.put_nowait((status, host))
        # сообщаем о выполнении полученной задачи
        queue.task_done()

        print '{} finished. Result = {}'.format(host, status)


def main():
    start_time = time.time()

    # Для получения задач и выдачи результата используем очереди
    queue = Queue()
    result_queue = Queue()

    fr_success = os.path.join(domain_temp, "req-good.txt")
    fr_errors = os.path.join(domain_temp, "req-error.txt")


    # Сначала загружаем все URL из файла в очередь задач
    with open(domain_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            queue.put(line.strip())

    # Затем запускаем необходимое количество потоков
    for i in range(theard_count):
        thread = Thread(target=run, args=(queue, result_queue))
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    # И ждем, когда задачи будут выполнены
    queue.join()
    # После чего пишем результаты в файлы
    with open(fr_success, 'w') as fs, open(fr_errors, 'w') as fe:
        while not result_queue.empty():
            status, host = result_queue.get_nowait()

            if status:
                f = fs
            else:
                f = fe

            f.write(host)
            f.write('\n')

    print time.time() - start_time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Как записать результат в файл в таком формате: google.com - 1 "где 1 это ранг"  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в таком формате можете записывать несколькими способами:

```
rank = 1
```

1. f строки

   ```
   result = f'google.com - {rank}'
   ```
2. через метод `format`

   ```
   result = 'google.com - {}'.format(rank)
   ```
3. конкатенация строк

   ```
   result = 'google.com - ' + str(rank)
   ```

ну а затем пишите свой результат в файл

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(result)
```

Comment: Rank мне не известен он берется с алексы , и какой сайт я тоже за ранее не могу знать, посмотрите на мой код еще раз , как его корректировать чтобы я могу записать в таком формате , на данный момент пишется только host

Comment: @DarkFox777 rank я привел для примера для вывода он не важно какой будет все равно будет работать

Comment: я просто не могу понять как мне из функции check_url(host)  вытащить результат rank и поместить в функцию main()

Comment: @DarkFox777 так возвращайте результат из функции и используйте его, и вообще у вас каждая функция должна выполнять конкретную задачу, в концепции `chek_url` что то плохо понятно что она еще и rank возвращает

Comment: @lldar Я не сильно селен в питоне, только начинаю изучать по этому обратился за помощью )